# Meaning of "Bump" on forums

Tags: meaning

A guy posted something on (or in?) a forum. Another one posted "bump". Sometimes it's the same guy. What does it mean?

In dictionaries, *bump* is typically defined as (as a noun) a small raised protuberance, or (as a verb) colliding with or striking something. It is unclear how the usual definitions of the word would apply in this situation.

Comment: It means he or she is trying to "bump" the topic back up, into the first page of the forum. You see people doing that when they have a topic that they think deserves more activity.

Comment: @user3109672 You're right, but comments aren't forever; You should put that answer in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per a comment from user3109672:

> It means he or she is trying to "bump" the topic back up, into the first page of the forum. You see people doing that when they have a topic that they think deserves more activity.